# modx migx. How to start idx from 6?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, idx, migx

I need the numbering of idx to start from 6 instead of 1. How can I achieve this?
It's my code:

```
<div class="pp-quote li-quote-[[+idx]]" data-textquote="quote-text-[[+idx]]">
  <div class="img animated bounce">
      <img src="[[+image:phpthumbof=`w=168&h=168&zc=1`]]" width="168" height="168" alt="Image">
    </div>
</div>
```

I set the offset to 6 for the output, but the numbers in the ID are not displaying correctly, although the images are.

```
 [[getImageList?
                                &tvname=`landing_portfolio-images`
                                &tpl=`tpl-landing_portfolio-right-side`
                                &offset=`6`
                                &limit=`6`
                                ]]
```

Comment: I don't think you can change this. In the documentation it clearly states that the idx always begins with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getImageList `reverse` param, maybe this will be helpful. Anyway you can always wrap `[[+idx]]` with custom snippet, please let me know if this is still actual for you, I'll show how.